# NativeScript HTTP:getJSON doesn't work

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I have used the original helloworld app and just change the model from HelloWorldModel to MainModel.

Then i required "http" but when i run the app and klik the button for "updateAction" it only writes to the console and sets the message.

The HTTP request doesn't do anything.

Code: (main-view-model.js)

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function(d, b) {
for (var p in b)
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];

function __() {
    this.constructor = d;
}
__.prototype = b.prototype;
d.prototype = new __();
};
var observable = require("data/observable");
var http = require("http");
var MainModel = (function(_super) {
    __extends(MainModel, _super);

function MainModel() {
    _super.call(this);
    console.log("MainModel called");
    this.set("message", "Last updated" + " 2015-07-22 00:00:00");
    this.set("message2", "Last updated" + " 2015-07-22 00:00:00");
}
MainModel.prototype.updateAction = function() {
    console.log("updateAction");
    this.set("message2", "Last updated" + " 2015-07-22 01:00:00");
    http.getJSON("https://httpbin.org/get").then(function(r) {
        this.set("message", "Last updated \n" + r);
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(r);
    }, function(e) {
        // Argument (e) is Error!
        console.log("FAIL");
        console.log(e);
        this.set("message", "Last updated \n" + e);
    });
};
return MainModel;
})(observable.Observable);
exports.MainModel = MainModel;
exports.mainViewModel = new MainModel();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm testing on iPhone 6 emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using getString works and gives the same response.

Still wierd the getJSON doesn't work.

A working example is:

```
http.getString("https://httpbin.org/get").then(function (r) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(r);
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("FAIL");
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: i tried getString but always getting connection timeout error

Comment: It works for me in the emulator on ios. How are you testing it? @AtulChaudhary

Comment: Form me it is working fine in emulator but doesn't work in actual device. Always getting an error request time out

Comment: It was my firewall and that's why it was working from emulator not from device